# Why am I getting two sets of data from one api call using Fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, api, foreach

When I fetch the api json data, I get double the results. Using `.forEach()` method, I get the double data printed to the HTML which I only need one set.

Here is my api call and the loop

```
var url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1geede';

fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data =>  {

const scope = data.data.messages;
        console.log(scope);

        //Looping through the user data

        scope.forEach((i) => {

            let user = i;

            if (user.username == "Mygel van Trabel") {

                user1( user.focused, user.message, getTimeStamp(user.timestamp), user.username);

            } else {

                user2( user.focused, user.message, getTimeStamp(user.timestamp), user.username);

            }



        });

}).catch( error => console.error(error));
```

User1 and User2 are functions. Here is the results from `console.log(scope)`:

```
VM  app.js:20 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
app.js:20     (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Right now it's printing both of the sets into the DOM when I only need just one. Why is that happening?

The picture below is what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

This picture is the results it's giving me now

[image]

Comment: What are the `user1` and `user2` functions? Works fine without that: https://jsfiddle.net/bvsLueky/

Comment: I just added them to the post

Comment: It looks like they're not logging anything, but without them, as you can see from the fiddle, the data isn't duplicated (eg 4 items are displayed, not 8). Can you show code that demonstrates a [MCVE]?

Comment: @CertainPerformance How?

Comment: I don't know - it's up to you to create a [MCVE], else the question will be unanswerable

Comment: @CertainPerformance I just shortened the code. I hope that meets MCVE.

Comment: The problem still can't be reproduced from the code - see the JSFiddle. There are 4 items printed, not 8.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191577/discussion-between-michael-stokes-and-certainperformance).

Comment: Could you check your network tab to confirm the request is only send 1 time, and [edit] your post to include this information? This is the most common case for dublicates logging

Comment: Hi @MichaelStokes, I'm curious if you checked the Network Tab to confirm the number of request, as suggested by Ferrybig?

Comment: @Jack Yes and I'm still working on it now. I do see two fetch requests. One from VM and the other from app.js. They are both being printed to the HTML.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question, I clearly did the best I could to explain the issue and posted relevant code.

Comment: @MichaelStokes, gotcha! I didn't downvote, but see you included additional information (so threw an upvote your way to offset! :) ) - One thing you may want to do is add a `debugger` statement before your console log and walk up the stack trace to see who is invoking the fetch calls - if indeed you have multiple fetch calls being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't mind, but I checked out your profile and noticed the files in your Github. The issue is in `src/index.html`, where you define `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` on line 35.

[image]

However, when you run Webpack, it will build and inject the same line (as seen in `dist/index.html`), resulting in your duplicate API calls.

[image]

The fix is just to remove line 35 from `/src/index.html` :) You will no longer have the dupe JS calling the API.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is working fine. If you check `console.log` of your `scope` variable for which you are running the `forEach` then you find that scope contains the duplicated data so it doesn't have any issue with your `forEach` loop.

```js
fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1geede')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(function(data) {
    //Declaring the scope variable for user data
    const scope = data.data.messages;

    console.log("Duplication is here: ", scope);
    console.log("---------");

    //Looping through the user data
    scope.forEach((i) => {
        let user = i;

        console.log(user);
    });
});
```

Comment: His issue is that he was seeing 8 results, not 4.

Comment: @CertainPerformance If that is the case then why we are not seeing the 8 results with his provided code?

Comment: Because OP has not provided a [MCVE]. (If his problem cannot be reproduced, best to ask for clarification and vote to close)